# Meaning of Zekher Livracha (ז"ל - Of blessed memory)

Tags: blessing, hashkafah-philosophy, words, death, kavod

The literal translation of ז"ל is "of blessed memory"

What does it mean to bless memory? How does it help the soul?

Comment: There's no such wording "זכר לברכה" in our sources. You should change it to "זכרונו לברכה".

Comment: @AlBerko That's not true. King Solomon used that wording, for instance

Answer (score 1):

Kiddushin 31b:

> במותו כיצד היה אומר דבר שמועה מפיו לא יאמר כך אמר אבא אלא כך אמר אבא מרי הריני כפרת משכבו והני מילי תוך שנים עשר חדש מכאן ואילך אומר זכרונו לברכה לחיי העולם הבא
>
> How [does one honor his parent] in [the parent’s] death? If he is saying something he heard from him, he shouldn’t say, “So did Father say,” but rather “So did Father, my teacher, say; may I be an atonement for his resting [soul].” This is within twelve months; from then on, he says, “May his memory be a blessing, for the life of the World to Come.”

As Rashi explains:

> מכאן ואילך - כבר קבל מה שקבל שאין משפט רשעי ישראל בגיהנם אלא י"ב חדש:
>
> ”From then on” - He has already received what he has received, for the judgement of the wicked Jews in Gehenom is only 12 months.

Seemingly, the idea is that we bless the deceased that he merit complete enjoyment in the World to Come.

Lest you say that “his memory be a blessing” and “his memory be a blessing for the life of the World to Come” be two different things, see how the Shulchan Aruch (YD 240:9) codifies this Halacha:

> חייב לכבדו אפי' אחר מותו כיצד היה אומר דבר שמועה מפיו אומר כך אמר אבא מרי הריני כפרת משכבו אם הוא תוך שנים עשר חדש ואם הוא לאחר שנים עשר חדש אומר זכרונו לברכה:
>
> One is obligated to honor him even after his death. How do? If he is saying something he heard from him, he says, “So did Father, my teacher, may I be an atonement for his resting [soul]” if it’s within 12 months. If it’s after twelve months, he says, “May his memory be for a blessing.”

Even if the Shulchan Aruch had a different reading of the Gemara, he was certainly aware of Rashi’s interpretation of it, as he directly quotes him in Beis Yosef ad. loc.:

> חייב לכבדו אפי' לאחר מותו כיצד היה אומר דבר שמועה מפיו וכו' ברייתא שם (לא:) ופירש"י הריני כפרת משכבו. עלי יבא כל רע הראוי לבא על נפשו: לאמר שנים עשר חדש. כבר קבל מה שקבל שאין משפט רשעי ישראל בגיהנם אלא י"ב חדש:

Comment: Perhaps the ShA had a different Girsa? Indeed many old manuscripts don't have the word לברכה in the Gemara

Comment: Regarding the last point, and @DoubleAA 's comment, see Aruch Hashulchan Y.D. 240:30: אבל לאחר י"ב חדש לא יאמר כן שהרי כבר קיבל דינו אלא יאמר זכרונו לברכה כן הלשון בטור וש"ע סעי' ט' ע"ש וברמב"ם הלשון זכרונו לחיי העולם הבא ובגמ' הגירסא זכרונו לברכה לחיי העולם הבא ע"ש ולא ידעתי אם הטור וש"ע ס"ל דלאו דווקא הוא ודי כשיאמר זכרונו לברכה או שלא חשו להאריך ונראה כסברא ראשונה וכן המנהג לאמר רק ז"ל וכן בכתיבה ויש מקצת מדקדקים כותבים זללה"ה

Comment: @Alex Interesting. B”N I’ll take a look at that later.

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhrmt.jpg) is the Munich manuscript without לברכה.

Answer (score 0):

THe Midrash Bereyshis Rabba 49a says:

> "רבי יצחק פתח (משלי י, ז): "**זֵכֶר צַדִּיק לִבְרָכָה וְשֵׁם רְשָׁעִים יִרְקָב**" .
>   אמר רבי יצחק כל מי שהוא מזכיר את הצדיק ואינו מברכו עובר בעשה מה טעמיה "זֵכֶר צַדִּיק לִבְרָכָה".
>   וכל מי שהוא מזכיר את הרשע ואינו מקללו עובר בעשה מה טעמיה "וְשֵׁם רְשָׁעִים יִרְקָב".

Acc. to this Midrash everyone who mentions the name of a Tzaddik has to add "Zichrono Livraha" (and the opposite with the wicked) because the Possuk says "זכר צדיק לברכה" meaning "if you mention a Tzaddik - bless him".

So literally, Z"l does not mean "his memory blessed", but actually **"when mentioned (זכרונו) - blessed (לברכה)"**.

---

I don't know how and if it helps the soul, it just means we treat him as a Tzaddik. That's all.

Comment: @Al There’s a difference between ז״ל and זצ״ל

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90997/discussion-between-micha-berger-and-double-aa).